# How can I prepend a statement to the script generated by gradle in distTar?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm currently working on project using gradle 2.1 and I want to prepend a command to the script that gradle creates and puts into the `/bin/` directory of the created tar archive. (I'm using the application plugin). How can I achiev this, or is it not possible?

The problem I am trying to solve is, that the gradle build automatically builds multiple docker images and starts up the container. The `CMD` for each container points to the script created by gradle. But now I want to start `mongoDB` before the application starts.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally found a solution to the problem [here](http://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-application-plugin-app_home-in-applicationdefaultjvmargs/)

Its fairly simple. You can add manipulate `unixScript.text` or `windowsScript.text` in the `startScripts` task resulting in something like this:

```
startScript << {
    unixScript.text = "<your command here>" + unixScrip.text
    windowsScript.text = "<your command here>" + windowsScript.text
}
```